# Plot numpy array using matplotlib - Python

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two `numpy` `array` using `matplotlib` but I am not getting the right layout of the figures. Below the code I am using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data.shape
(2, 766, 1398) # values between -1/+1

f = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
f.add_subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(data[0], cmap="RdYlGn")
plt.colorbar()

f.add_subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(data[1], cmap="RdYlGn")
plt.colorbar()
```

The output I am getting (in `Jupyter Notebook`) looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to link the size of the bar with the size of the image? I have been checking some online tutorials and using this same code they get a proper output. What I am missing?

In addition, my `data` array could have a shape of `(3, 766, 1398)`, `(4, 766, 1398)`, `(5, 766, 1398)`, etc. So I would like to automaticallly shape the subplot size to the dimensions of my array. So if I have `(2, 766, 1398)`, 1 row and 2 column should be fine. If 3, 2 rows - 2 columns; if 4 2rows - 2 columns, if 5 3 rows - colums, etc.

Would that be possible with `matplotlib`?

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: This is shown in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_colorbar_with_axes_divider.html).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I managed to reproduced the example but not sure in which part I should insert my `numpy array` `data`.

Comment: `im1 = ax1.imshow(data[0])`?

Comment: Just tried also and yes it works like that but I am getting small figures. In my question I use `figsize=(15,15)` to increase the size but in this case, where does it go? Any idea how to link the size of the subplot with the dimensions of my `array`?

Comment: Okay just found out that, ` plt.subplots(1, 2,figsize=(15,15))`